# How to remove the google icon in header from the google translate

Tags: php, html, css

**I am using this line of code:**

```
 <style>
    .goog-te-gadget-icon{
    background:none !important;
    }
    .goog-te-banner-frame {
     //left: -150px !important;
     display:none;
     background-color:#000 ;!important;
    }
    div.goog-te-gadget-simple{ border-radius:5px; background-color:#000; padding:10px;}
    a.goog-te-menu-value{ text-decoration:none;}
    a.goog-te-menu-value > span{ color:#FFF;}
    </style>
 <div id="google_translate_element"></div>
<script>
   function googleTranslateElementInit() {
      var translator = new google.translate.TranslateElement({
      pageLanguage: 'en',
      includedLanguages: 'en,zh-CN,zh-TW',

      layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE
   }, 'google_translate_element');
}
</script>
<script src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>


                               </div>
```

**Here is the output and I want to remove the icon, how can possibly remove it? or hide**
[image]

Comment: It's not clear what you actually want removed. Is it the blue icon next to "translate"? Or the entire header? Or the "Google" logo? etc.

Answer (score 3):

Add below CSS for remove translate toolbar and text tooltip.

```
.goog-te-banner-frame.skiptranslate, .goog-te-gadget-icon {
    display: none !important;
}
body {
    top: 0px !important;
}
.goog-tooltip {
    display: none !important;
}
.goog-tooltip:hover {
    display: none !important;
}
.goog-text-highlight {
    background-color: transparent !important;
    border: none !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Hi himansu, i have one more question can you tell me how to add flag language wise  in dropdown?

Comment: For that you must integrate costume Google translate with list structure(UL,LI) See http://newsinfo-blog.blogspot.com/2015/05/custom-integratigration-of-google.html

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that removing the google icon is against their usage terms and therefore illegal.

Check if that google translate HTML snippet is rendered inside an iframe. If so then your CSS will not be able to modify it anyways. JavaScript could help here though.